# In Java should we use generics when dealing with multiple interfaces?

Tags: java, generics

Let's say I defined the following interfaces for position and time respectively:

```
public interface PositionBeep {

  double x();

  double y();

  PositionBeep generateNeighborAt(double angle, double distance);

}

public interface TimeBeep {

  long timestamp();

  void setTime(long timestamp);

}
```

and I want to create a new class that deals with a generic extending both these types:

```
class Sequence<T extends PositionBeep&TimeBeep> {

  T createSequence(T start, double angle) {
      T next = start.generateNeighborAt(angle,1000);
      next.setTime(start.timestamp()+1000);
      ...
  }

}
```

I know that this does not work because generateNeighborAt returns PositionBeep and not PositionBeep&TimeBeep. The problem is related to my choice in separating the concepts of time and space and then attempting to merge them again using generics, hence one possible solution would be to join these two interfaces. Although I can accept this, I was wondering if there are other suitable approaches that allows me to keep these two concepts separately and still be able to implement a 'createSequence' method with both concepts?

Thanks

Comment: Can you make `PositionBeep` and `TimeBeep` implement another interface, let's say, `GenericBeep` and use it in your `Sequence` class?

Comment: yes, but having a GenericBeep instance, how can I access the methods specific to PositionBeep and TimeBeep?

Comment: The problem here is your `generateNeighborAt` method. Compiler cant handle situation when it returns non `TimeBeep` for you.

Answer (score 0):

I highly suspect this is a troll question, but nevertheless. In your case, you have a generic method that accepts T, and for that you don’t need to make the entire class parameterized, just make the method parameterized.

Comment: I don't understand why you would suspect that, is it such a dumb question? The class is generic because it contains other methods using T, nevertheless I don't  see how having the method as generic instead of the class would change anything in this particular scenario.. what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

One approach you can take is to enhance your `generateNeighborAt` method to handle returning of `PositionBeep` subclasses.

```
public interface PositionBeep {

        double x();

        double y();

        <PB extends PositionBeep> PB generateNeighborAt(Class<PB> clazz, double angle, double distance);

      }

class Sequence<T extends PositionBeep&TimeBeep> {

          Class<T> type;

          T createSequence(T start, double angle) {
              T next = start.generateNeighborAt(type, angle,1000);
              next.setTime(start.timestamp()+1000);
              return null;
          }

        }
```

The reason I introduces `Class` parameter is to make sure `generateNeighborAt` has a way to determine what type of subclass calling client needs.